# Import of framework in swift bridging header not recognised upon archive

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, asyncdisplaykit

I import the Facebook AsyncDisplayKit framework into my app using the swift bridging header, like so:

```
#import <AsyncDisplayKit/AsyncDisplayKit.h>
```

It's always worked fine for building and running my app, but when I go to archive, it gives me an error:

> ## import  'file not found'

Why might this not be recognized, upon archiving?

Comment: Any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I always meet this kind of problem. I think you can try to check your `file&folder hierarchy`.

- Such as you have a root folder named `Project`, as is often the case, there is another `Project` in your previous `Project`, the root folder.
- And Checking the `Objective-C Bridging Header` in the `Build Setting`. Sometime error can occurred for `Project/Project/Bridging-Header.h`. And the error can be corrected by changing the definition as `Project/Bridging-Header.h`.

If the location of `Bridging-Header.h` is not matching with the definition in the `Build Setting`, the error like `import file not found` will occur.

I just tell your my solution for `Bridging` issue I already met, I hope it can help you.